# Flutter doctor after update 1.2.1 gives two android studio versions

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have updated flutter with version 1.2.1 and while running flutter doctor -v I got error saying I have to install flutter in android studio 3.2 But I am using Android studio 3.3.1. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If you don't use `3.2` the red cross does not matter. That's just information.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer. It worked